# none is saving in django admin

Tags: django, ajax, knockout.js

**productscreate.html**

```
<form data-bind="submit: save" method="post">  
  {% csrf_token %}
   
    <table border="1">
<tr>
    <td>Title:
    <input type="text" name="title" id="title" data-bind="value: $data.title"></td>
    <br>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Description:
    <textarea name="description" id="description" data-bind="value: $data.description">Description</textarea></td>
    <br>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Image:
    <input type="file" name="image" id="image" ></td>
    <br>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><button type="button" id="submit" data-bind="click: save">Submit</button></td>
</tr>

</table>
</form>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.5.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script>
  function getCookie(name) {
      let cookieValue = null;
      if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
          const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
          for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
              const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
              // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
              if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                  cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                  break;
              }
          }
      }
      return cookieValue;
  }
  const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken'); 
</script>
<script>

  var ViewModel = function () {

    var self = this;
    self.title = ko.observable("");
    self.description = ko.observable("");
 

    var FormData = {
        title: self.title,
        description: self.description,
  
    };
    console.log(FormData);
    self.save = function () {
       
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/productsadd',                                           
            data: FormData,
            contentType: "application/json",
            headers: {'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken},
            cache: false,
            enctype: "multipart/form-data",
            //processData: false,
            success: function (FormData) {
              alert("successfull")
              window.location = '{% url "productslist" %}'; 
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("fail");
            }
        });
    };
    };
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel())

    </script>
```

**views.py**

```
class ProductsCreate(CreateView):
   model = Products
   template_name = "productscreate.html"
   fields = ['title', 'description', 'image']
   success_url=reverse_lazy('productslist')

def productsAdd(request):
    if request.is_ajax and request.method == "POST":
        product=Products()
        product.title = request.POST.get('title')
        product.description = request.POST.get('description')
        # product.image = request.FILES['image']
        product.save()
        return render(request,'productslist.html')
    else:
        return render(request,'productscreate.html')

class ProductsDetailView(DetailView):
     template_name = "productsdetail.html"
     queryset = Products.objects.all()
     context_object_name = 'products'
     model = Products
```

**models.py**

```
class Products(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    image = models.FileField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
         return str(self.title)
```

[image]
When i create a product in form it save as none in django admin I don't know where is the issue
I have given html with knockout js and ajax,views and models
I want to submit title,description and image in django admin using form in createproduct html
Please help me to solve this
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to print ``request.POST.get('title')`` and see what's output

Comment: I print the title but nothing shows in output

Comment: Can you check if FormData in your js code contains the desired title?

Comment: Yes FormData is working. When i print console.log(FormData);  it also shows output in console but it is saving none in admin

Comment: Hello @RanjithaSanker can you explain what's the behavior of your form when you submit it it's reloading the page or it's sending ajax  request without reloading page and does data which is None is getting saved everytime when you send request?

Comment: Everytime when i submit the form it is saving as none in database and django admin

Comment: Try to print ``request.POST`` and add output in your question by making an [edit]

Comment: How to print request.POST in views.py

Comment: @RanjithaSanker You've to add this line inside if block like this ``if request.is_ajax and request.method == "POST":print(request.POST)``

Comment: Ok I have given that but how to run the code in vs code